# How to bind a ICommand into a Button out of DataContext?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding, icommand

i have a Button into a DataGrid with a DataContext (KeyValuePair).
I want to implementing a Command into this Button.
But if i use the Command="{Binding CommandoTest}" it didnt work.

I tested the ICommand into a Grid without DataContext and it works well.

```
                <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonList.Keys}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Button Command="{Binding CommandoTest}" Content="CommandoTest"></Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

The Command Code:

```
Public ReadOnly Property CommandoTest As ICommand
    Get
        Return CommandTest_exp
    End Get
End Property


Public Sub CommandTest_exp()
    MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the `DataGrid` is inside of some element whose `DataContext` is the one with the `CommandoTest` property on it.

If that is the case, using the example of a `Grid` as the parent, you could use:

```
<Grid x:Name="parent_grid">
    <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonList.Keys}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandoTest, ElementName=parent_grid}" Content="CommandoTest"></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Another approach, in which you don't have to name any controls, would be (this wouldn't work for the `Grid` in the previous example, as it would first find the `Grid` which is the parent of your `Button`, so I've added another parent element of type `Border`):

```
<Border>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding PersonList.Keys}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.CommandoTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Border}}}" Content="CommandoTest"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```